# excel selected cell in named ranged column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I thought this would be a simple answers but cant find it anywhere

I have a macro based on the selected cell which is run in a right click context menu.

I need to get the column number based on where the cell is in a named range.

Example
Named Range = C4:H9
selected cell = E6
Value i am trying to get is = 3

E which is 5th column - C which is 3rd column + 1 because column number is not 0 based.

Is there an easy way to do this on a line like
Range("namedRange").columnDif(selectedCell)

Comment: Why not just look for its own column and then subtract the offset of A to the start?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
Dim namedRangeFirstCol: namedRangeFirstCol = Range("Test").Column
Dim namedRangeLastCol: namedRangeLastCol = namedRangeFirstCol + Range("Test").Columns.Count - 1

If Selection.Column >= namedRangeFirstCol And Selection.Column <= namedRangeLastCol Then
   MsgBox Selection.Column - Range("Test").Column + 1
End If
```

The IF statement is just to check that the selected cell is actually within the range. You may only need `Selection.Column - Range("Test").Column + 1`